# How to get creation date of a file using Scala

Tags: scala

One of the requirements in my project needs to check if the file's creation date and determine if it is older than 2 days from current day. In Java, there is something like below code which can get us the file's creation date and other information.

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
```

But I don't know how to write the same code in Scala. Could anyone let me know how the same can be implemented in Scala.

Answer (score 4):

**Java**

The preferred way to do this is using the newer `java.nio.file` API:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```

You can access the modified time (along with much else) in `Files`:

```
FileTime modified = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path)
```

This gives you a `FileTime`, which may be converted to a `java.time.Instant`

```
Instant modifiedInstant = modified.toInstant();
```

You can then do this, with:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

boolean isMoreThan2DaysOld = modifiedInstant.plus(2, DAYS).isBefore(Instant.now())
```

**Scala**

All of this is accessible from scala (unless you are using ScalaJS):

```
import java.nio.file._; import java.time._; import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS
val isMoreThan2DaysOld 
  = Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toInstant.plus(2, DAYS) isBefore Instant.now
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_152).

import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

val pathStr = "/tmp/test.sql"

Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(pathStr), classOf[BasicFileAttributes])

Files.readAttributes(Paths.get(pathStr), classOf[BasicFileAttributes]).creationTime
```

```
res3: java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime = 2018-03-06T00:25:52Z
```